# iOS GData multiple youtube uploads

Tags: ios, youtube, gdata

I am making an application that needs to upload several videos to youtube. THe problem with GData is that I don't know how to pass information to its callback function so I can distinguish between different uploads.

```
(void)uploadTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
   finishedWithEntry:(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)videoEntry
               error:(NSError *)error
```

In ASIHttpRequest there is the "userInfo" property to allow the user to pass information to the requestFinish callback. What about in GData youtube upload requests?

```
- (void)uploadToYoutube: (NSString *)login andPassword:(NSString *)password withVideo:(NSData *)videoData forSighting:(SightingDB *)sighting {


    [service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:DEVELOPER_KEY];

    NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];


    NSString *titleStr =  @"title";

    // gather all the metadata needed for the mediaGroup

    GDataMediaTitle *title = [GDataMediaTitle textConstructWithString:titleStr];
    [titleStr release];

    NSString *categoryStr = @"Entertainment";
    GDataMediaCategory *category = [GDataMediaCategory mediaCategoryWithString:categoryStr];
    [category setScheme:kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory];

    NSString *descStr = @"descripion"

    GDataMediaDescription *desc = [GDataMediaDescription textConstructWithString:descStr];
    [descStr release];

    NSArray *kwords = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"xxx",@"weee",nil];
    GDataMediaKeywords *keywords = [GDataMediaKeywords keywordsWithStrings:kwords];



    BOOL isPrivate = NO;

    GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
    [mediaGroup setMediaTitle:title];
    [mediaGroup setMediaDescription:desc];
    [mediaGroup addMediaCategory:category];
    [mediaGroup setMediaKeywords:keywords];
    [mediaGroup setIsPrivate:isPrivate];

    NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:@""
                                               defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

    // create the upload entry with the mediaGroup and the file data
    GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;

    entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                          data:videoData
                                                      MIMEType:mimeType
                                                          slug:@"movie.mov"];



    SEL progressSel = @selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
    [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];

    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
    ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                      forFeedURL:url
                                        delegate:self
                               didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The ticket supports setProperty:forKey: as well as setUserData:.

Or just use blocks callbacks rather than a delegate and selector.